# Adding specified number of Ellipses on Picturebox VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, picturebox

I am trying to draw multiple Ellipses on PictureBox control in VB.Net on MouseClick event.

All I want to do is on every mouse click, a new ellipse to be drawn on picturebox till the specified number is reached.

My code so far is as below:

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click, PictureBox1.MouseClick
    Dim DrwCount As Integer
    Dim regcount As Integer = Val(ComboBox1.Text)
    bPen.width = 2.0F
    GFX.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias

    txtValueX.Text = e.X.ToString
    txtValueY.Text = e.Y.ToString

    For DrwCount = 0 To DrwCount < RegCount
        GFX.DrawRectangle(bPen, e.X - 2, e.Y - 2, 40, 40)
        Label27.Text = "Draw Count " & DrwCount
        PictureBox1.Image = myBitmap
        DrwCount = DrwCount + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

When I run this code, the drwcount reaches the specified number with only one ellipse on the picturebox.

Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

> For DrwCount = 0 To DrwCount < RegCount

`DrwCount < RegCount` evaluates to a boolean.  In VB, False can be coerced to 0, and True to 1.

So the line, after coercing, looks like:

```
For DrwCount = 0 To 0
```

Obviously that's not your intent.  You probably wanted:

```
For DrwCount = 0 To RegCount
```

Additionally, the `For` statement will increment the indexer variable automatically each loop iteration, unlike the `While` or `Do` statements.